# Profiling recursive code in C#/Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling

I have some code in C#, using Visual Studio 2019. To simplify, the structure of the code looks like this:

```
public class Program
{
    private static async Task Main()
    {
        Perft.RunPerft(5);
    }
}

public class Perft
{        
    Board board = new Board();

    public static void RunPerft(int depth)
    {
        if (depth == 0) return 1;

        board.GetAllMoves();

        int _nodes = 0;
        foreach (Move move in board.moves)
        {
            if (board.MakeMove(move))
            {
                _nodes += PerftRun(depth - 1);
                board.UnmakeMove(move);
            }
        }

        return _nodes;
    }       
}
```

So I have 3 main functions that I want to know the performance of: GetAllMoves, MakeMove, and UnmakeMove. Is there an easy way to see how much time is spent in each of these functions? Maybe something built in in Visual Studio, instead of using stopwatches?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the oldie-but-goody method I would do, and have done many times, is this...

First, wrap a loop around the outer call, so it takes plenty of time, like 10 seconds or more. For example, if you loop it a million times, the number of seconds it takes altogether is the number of microseconds one call takes.

Second, while it is running, manually pause it 10 or 20 times. Each time, record the call stack.

Third, look at the stacks. The fraction of them containing `UnmakeMove` and each of your other routines is the fraction of time each routine takes. (Roughly. Unless you like decimal places, roughly is usually good enough.)
That fraction, divided by the number of times the routine is called, times the number of microseconds of one overall call is the microseconds of that routine.

Comment: Sorry. Do you know if can I make a Unit Test and encapsulate the method in a loop inside the Unit Test,  in order to get a real time consumption of the process. Or the time will be different from the consumption (of that method only) in the executable/project?

Comment: You can get an imperfect measure of the time the method takes by writing a unit test that measures the total time it takes to execute it N times, and then divide that time by N. This measure will not be perfect because the executions after the first will be faster than the first one, because the code will be cached. But it's better than nothing. On the other hand, it may be a better measure, because the method may also remain in the cache when it executes in reality.